# Plotting pandas time and category

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I really can't get out of this. Here is my table:

where grade can be A,B,C

```
doc_id, grade, timestamp
1, A, 27/01/15
2, A, 27/01/15
3, B, 27/01/15
...
```

My aim is to show a graph with three lines, showing how many A, B and C I got through time.

I can only think of this:

```
docs[docs['grade']== 'A'].groupby('time').count()
docs[docs['grade']== 'B'].groupby('time').count()
docs[docs['grade']== 'C'].groupby('time').count()
```

and combine them some how, but it is already clear I am on the wrong way,

any hint?

Comment: What is the exact data time in the `timestamp` column?  Are they strings, timestamps or datetimes?

Comment: Also, do you want a cumulative count?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['timestamp', 'grade']).grade.size().unstack().cumsum().ffill().fillna(0)
```

It basically pivots by date and grade, rolling forward the cumulative sum.

```
>>> df2
grade       A  B   C
timestamp           
4/1/15      0  1   0
4/11/15     4  1   2
4/3/15      4  4   2
4/4/15      4  5   3
4/5/15      4  6   3
4/6/15      7  6   6
4/8/15      9  6   8
4/9/15     13  7  12
```

[image]

If you don't want a cumulative sum, you can just use:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['timestamp', 'grade']).grade.size().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the `input_data` be

```
       grade timestamp
doc_id                
1          A  27/01/15
2          A  27/01/15
3          B  27/01/15
4          C  27/01/15
5          A  27/01/16
6          A  27/01/16
7          A  27/01/16
8          B  27/01/16
9          B  27/01/16
10         C  27/01/16
11         A  27/01/16
12         B  27/01/16
13         C  27/01/16
14         C  27/01/16
```

So to show a graph with three lines, showing how many A, B and C you got through time, you can use

```
result = input_data.groupby(['timestamp']).apply(lambda x: x.grade.value_counts())
```

The output would be something like this

```
           A  B  C
timestamp         
27/01/15   2  1  1
27/01/16   4  3  3
```

You can plot the data using `result.plot()`.